# Estoy teniendo un problema con esta consigna

Tags: c

*Hola estoy teniendo un problema con este ejercicio de listas.*

***Escribir un programa que lea desde un archivo un texto que contiene una cantidad desconocida
de palabras (una en cada línea) y genere una lista ordenada de todas las palabras existentes en
el texto con su frecuencia de aparición.***

*Mi problema es que solo lee solo la primera linea del archivo (En el archivo que estoy usando tengo varias palabras) y luego cuando la quiero mostrar me tira basura y la verdad es que no estoy viendo el error. Estoy haciendo unas "pruebas de escritorio" para ver cual es el problema y creo que lo estoy haciendo bien.
Desde ya gracias por la respuesta...*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct nodo{
    char *dato;
    int cont;
    struct nodo *sig;
}NodoL;
typedef NodoL* Tlista;

void insertarOrdenado(Tlista *,char st[]);
void cargarLista(Tlista *);
int yaExiste(Tlista,char st[]);
void mostrarLista(Tlista);

int main(){
    Tlista l=NULL;
    cargarLista(&l);
    mostrarLista(l);
    return 0;
}

void insertarOrdenado(Tlista *L,char *st){
    Tlista aux,ant,act;
    aux=(Tlista)malloc(sizeof(NodoL));
    aux->dato=st;
    aux->sig=NULL;
    printf("-> %s\n",st);                           //valor=strcmp(strin1,strin2);
    if (*L==NULL || strcmp(st,(*L)->dato)==-1){      //valor==-1;strin1<strin2
        aux->sig=*L;                                //valor==0; strin1==strin2
        *L=aux;
        printf("--> %s\n",(*L)->dato);                                   //valor==1; strin1>strin2
    }else{
        ant=NULL;
        act=*L;
        while (act!=NULL && strcmp(st,(*L)->dato)==1){
            ant=act;
            act=act->sig;
        }
        aux->sig=act;
        ant->sig=aux;
    }
}

void cargarLista(Tlista *L){
    FILE *arch;
    char *st; //string dinamico
    st=(char*)malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    arch=fopen("tp6ej3.txt","r");

    while(!feof(arch)){
        fscanf(arch,"%s\n",st);
        printf("%s\n",st);
        if (!yaExiste(*L,st))
            insertarOrdenado(L,st);
        
    }
    fclose(arch);
    free(st);
}

int yaExiste(Tlista L,char *st){
    Tlista aux=L;
    while (aux!=NULL){
        if (strcmp(aux->dato,st)==0){
            return 1;
        }
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
    return 0;
}

void mostrarLista(Tlista L){
    Tlista aux=L;
    while (aux!=NULL){
        printf("%s",aux->dato);
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuántas letras tiene cada palabra? Estás reservando memoria con `malloc` para algo que equivale en tamaño a `char[9]` (pero `malloc` es mucho más lento), luego no lo estás limpiando (basta hacer `st[8]='\0'`, pero es mejor `memset (st, '\0', 9)`) antes de cada lectura. `aux->dato=st` copia el puntero `st`, pero lo estás liberando al final de `cargarLista` con `free`. Sería mejor que la estructura tenga espacio para la cadena (`char[9]` en vez de `char*`) y copies con `strncpy`. Por favor corregí algunas de estas cosas y editá el código. Sino son muchas correcciones juntas.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿realmente se espera que lo resuelvas con listas enlazadas? Sobre todo si el archivo se vuelve muy grande, este problema es un candidato ideal a usar hashtables o (una forma parecida) un diccionario.

Comment: sisi es el tema que estamos usando en la facultad. Mi problema es que no resuelvo el problema, la forma en la que asigno y eso no es problema.

Comment: Te tira basura porque tenés basura en el búffer que imprimis. Tenés basura porque manejás mal la memoria y asignás mal y, a la hora de imprimir, el búffer no tiene lo que esperabas.

Comment: Por cierto, también inicializas `Tlista` a `NULL` y lo pasás para su uso. Y en sí mismo el `typedef` de `Tlista` es totalmente desrecomendado, sobre todo para un principiante. Fijate por ejemplo https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/process/coding-style.html#typedefs